# Trouble with reading XML data into a flot chart with JQuery

Tags: xml, jquery, flot

I'm at a standstill with this and was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. I configured this script and in my mind it should work, yet I get no data showing up, and when I try to console.log it says cost is not defined. heres the script:

```
function get_daygraphdata() {
$.ajax({
           type: "GET",
            url: "day.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            cache: false,
            success: function(xml){
            var dataset = new Array();
        var counter = 0;
$(xml).find('product1').each(function(){
dataset[counter] = new Array(2);
dataset[counter][0] = $(this).children("date").text();
dataset[counter][1] = $(this).children("cost").text();
counter++;
console.log(dataset);

var options = {
            xaxis: {
                mode: 'time', 
                timeformat: "%H:%M %p",
                minTickSize: [1, "hour"]
            }
        }

        var placeholder = $("#graph1");
        $.plot(placeholder, [{data: dataset, label: Cost}], options);

});
}})
}
get_daygraphdata();
setInterval(function() {
    get_daygraphdata();
}, 300000);     
})
```

The Xml data is as shown:

```
<graphdata>
  <product1>
    <date>243500000</date>
    <cost>17.85</cost>
    <date>245500000</date>
    <cost>14.65</cost>
    <date>248500000</date>
    <cost>16.22</cost>
  </product1>
</graphdata
```

my thought was that it should come out in an array (date, cost).The console.log spits out this

```
array[2] ->Which holds
0: "243500000245500000248500000122500000122900000130900000"
1: "17.8514.6516.2213.8713.8713.87"
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cost is not defined
```

Is there anyone that might know what I'm doing wrong? And why this is not reacting appropriately?

Comment: Ok I figured out the problem with the uncaught error making the graph not show up. It was due to the label: Cost. It needs to be reversed with the data. The only problem I may have now is displaying the data correctly at the moment flot will not display anything except the graph itself. If anyone knows how this might bee done  easily with json that might be helpful, I'm not really familiar with json though.

Comment: eh, I gave up and changed to JSON, worked easy after that.

Comment: does the documentation confirm that it supports XML? I went through the FAQs and there is not cue about that.